# Did the Doctor and Clara escape at the end of Sleep No More?

Tags: doctor-who

At the end of the Doctor Who episode Sleep No More, did the Doctor and Clara escape?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, at the end of Sleep No More, The Doctor and Clara are escaping on the TARDIS. The Sandmen are destroyed by the gravity of the planet, so they all die. As it all crashes, the TARDIS whooshes away to safety. In the end, The Doctor and his iconic heroics have saved the day...or have they?

***SPOILERS TO THOSE WHO HAVE NOT SEEN IT, ANSWER TO THOSE WHO HAVE***

> The Doctor does escape, but he fails to stop the enemy. At the end, the narrator says the whole episode was a way to disguise the electro-magnetic pulses that can chemically change your brain (MORPHEUS process). He then plays a sound (the pulse) and promptly says, "It tingles, doesn't it?" This marks the end of the episode.

In all, the Doc gets away safely but fails to save the day. Talk about running...

Comment: I have a feeling that we may see more on this in the future. Also I would thing that this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't think the spoiler is necessary, the question is about a specific episode and if someone was to search this, they'd obviously be interested in the ending.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they did. The last scene was the TARDIS dematerializing. The sandmen on the station (except the professor) were destroyed due to the Ge-Force.